# Why does the loop not break upon inputting -1?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to comeplete a library problem i got and i cant get the while loop to stop when i type -1. I need to arrange books in order of most recent and i thought of starting off with just the book numbers. but i can't seen to get it to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
    {
    int i, j, temp, bk_no[20],count=0;
    printf("==========ACCESSING LIBRARY==========\n");

    while(bk_no[count]!=-1)
        {
        printf("What is the books number in the series?\n");
        scanf("%d",&bk_no[count]);
        count++;
        }

    for ( i = 0; i<count; i++ )
        {
        printf("%d",bk_no[i]);
        }

    printf("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i<count; i++ )
        {
        for ( j = 0; j<count-i; j++ )
            {
            if ( bk_no[j]>bk_no[j+1] )
                {
                temp = bk_no[j];
                bk_no[j] = bk_no[j+1];
                bk_no[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    for ( i = 0; i<count; i++ )
        {
        printf("%d",bk_no[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

sence you are incrementing the value of the count the next time the while
    loop checks the condition it looks in a index forward to the one which is set
     -1

```
 //this is not the right code i am jush hilighting where you may have gone wrong
 while(bk_no[count]!=-1)
    {
    printf("What is the books number in the series?\n");
    scanf("%d",&bk_no[count]);
    count++;//sence you are incrementing the value of the count the next time the while
//loop checks the condition it looks in a index forward to the one which is set
 // -1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `bk_no[count]` you compare in the loop condition and the `bk_no[count]` where you read the `-1` are different because at the end of the loop, you increase `count`.

You could use a do-while loop or check immediately after reading input:

```
  while(count < sizeof bk_no/sizeof bk_no[0]) {
        printf("What is the books number in the series?\n");
        scanf("%d", &bk_no[count]);
        if (bk_no[count] == -1) break;
        count++;
  }
```

Note that `bk_no` can store only 20 elements. So, you can't increment it infinitely without checking whether it could overflow.

Also note scanf() isn't the best tool for interactive inputs. See: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 0):

See what happens at the end of each iteration of your `while` loop: You read into `bk_no[count]`, then you increase `count`, then control goes back to the beginning of the loop and you compare `book[count]` with `-1` *with the new value of `count`*. You're not comparing the last number you read from input but some unitialized memory that's waiting there prepared to store the result of the next read.

You'll need to compare and exit from within the cycle before the increment, for which you actually don't need any condition at its start anymore:

```
while(1)
    {
    printf("What is the books number in the series?\n");
    scanf("%d",&bk_no[count]);
    if(bk_no[count]!=-1) break;
    count++;
    }
```

**EDIT**: use that vacated condition space to check for array bound overflow as P.P. wrote!